# の(代名詞) after の adjectives

Tags: grammar, usage, particle-の

So, when we use the 代名詞　の, it goes like this:

> 美味しい**の**をください　Please give me the tasty **one**

> 静かな**の**はあれ　The quiet **one** is that one

But what happens with adjectives or nouns that take a の already?

> 最後のの？　最後なの？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such の is called 体言の代用 in school grammar, and it is usually taught that it can be replaced with (の)もの/(の)こと.

According to [a dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AE/#jn-171157):

- 体言(practically a synonym for noun) + の = <体言>のもの
- 活用語 (words with conjugation, including verb and adjective) + の = <活用語> nominalized.

A possible source of confusion is that の can be replaced with のもの or もの, and the grammar does not differentiate them. My guess is that のもの replaces の when preceded by a noun (the first case above) and もの when preceded by others. Not completely sure, though.

The answer to the question: because 最後 is a noun, the correct form is 最後の＝最後のもの.

===

Other examples: 二番目の = the second one / 僕の = mine / 人の = other people's (things) or someone else's (thing)

Comment: +1, but it may be worth noting clearly that 最後のの is always ungrammatical. You can say either 最後のをください or 最後のものをください, but not 最後ののをください.